# Interacting with contracts on Solidity 0.4.* and Solidity 0.5.* in Truffle v5

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-compile

I have a big contract **(A)** that is built using Solidity 0.4.25.
I also want to build several contracts **(B)** that will talk to **(A)**, but they will be built using Solidity 0.5.*.

As I understand, I will not be able to compile and test contracts **(A)** and **(B)** on `ganache-cli`. I have to change contract **(A)** to Solidity 0.5.* to make it work (I use truffle v5).

If I understand it correctly, I can only interact with contracts that use 0.4.* using an interface and those contracts have to be deployed on a test/main network?